# How do I get reports from before dates earlier than the date I created the job in Reporting API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm testing out the new Youtube Analytics Reporting API. However, it looks like I can only get reports from dates on the date I created the job that generates the reports and later. How can I get bulk data from earlier dates than this? Am I forced to use the Analytics API then?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to retrieve data in an older timeline **Youtube Analytics API** is recommended.

You can find the answer you are looking for in [Retrieve YouTube Analytics Data](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/#key-differences).

These are the possible data you can get from Analytics and Reporting API by date.

> **Feature**
>
> Date Ranges
>
> **YouTube Analytics API**
>
> Some API reports specify the date that user activity occurred. Some of those reports support dimensions to aggregate user activity metrics by 7-day periods, 30-day periods, or months.
>
> **YouTube Reporting API**
>
> All API reports specify the day that user activity occurred. Applications using the API can implement features to aggregate data for periodic intervals.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm already using the analytics API, but need to cut down on my credit usage and don't need that current data, so I thought I'd use Reporting API. Are you saying it's not possible?

Comment: I think you have to do it manually through Reporting API. Again referencing from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/#supported-reports): "Data that is available in one API might not be available in the other. For example, the YouTube Analytics API lets you retrieve user activity metrics on a weekly or monthly basis, but the YouTube Reporting API requires you to aggregate that data yourself."